# onBackPressed and call refresh function android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to refresh just one fragment that in an tab bar activity when I press the back button. How can i achieve that? What I tried

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null
>   object reference

**Fragment Profile**

```
public void refreshFragment(){
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
}
```

**Edit profile activity**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    FragmentProfile fragment = new FragmentProfile();
    fragment.refreshFragment();
}
```

Comment: remove `super.onBackPressed();` line

Comment: @VinayRathod not working..

Comment: try declaring `FragmentProfile fragment = new FragmentProfile();` as global and onBackPressed just check `if(fragment!=null) fragment.refreshFragment();`

Comment: @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(fragment!=null)
    fragment.refreshFragment();
}

Comment: why would you think a newly created, not-attached fragment would have a fragment manager? You need to apply the refresh to the fragment that already exists, not to a random newly created one.

Comment: @Lester Your question was incomplete . This is a simple use case of `startActivityForResult();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **SharedPreferences** to do this.

Step 1: create a constants class.

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String REFRESH = "refresh_content";
}
```

Step 2: put boolean to the constants.REFRESH on Edit Profile Activity,

```
private SharedPreferences pref;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rostering, container, false);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(Constants.REFRESH, true);
    editor.commit();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Step 3: Call refresh function on the onResume on Fragment Profile

```
private SharedPreferences pref;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(pref.getBoolean(Constants.REFRESH, false)){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(Constants.REFRESH, false);
        editor.commit();
        refreshFragment();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Although its a Conventional `java.lang.NullPointerException:` But I want make few things clear here for the cause of it .
1. `super.onBackPressed();` will `finish()` the `Activity` so you can not make any transactions on its BackStack.
2. You want to refresh fragment then you should get the current fragment from `FragmentManager` to Refresh it .

```
FragmentProfile fragment = new FragmentProfile();
```

This will give you a new `Fragment` which is not attached yet and calling anything on it does not make any sense . This is the reason `FragmentTransaction` is null  and `getActivity()` will be also null for new `Fragment`.

Cause `getFragmentManager()` by definition Returns the `FragmentManager` of `Activity`. And your new Fragment is not attached yet so it will return null.

> getFragmentManager()
>   Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated with this fragment's activity.

So your code should look like below .

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(SomeCondition) {
        FragmentProfile fragment = //Get the Fragment from Fragment Manager Here
        fragment.refreshFragment();
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

I have put a condition in `onBackPressed()` cause you do not want to completely disable the Back button. If you are using a Layout as container for Fragments you can get Fragment by following two methods in `Activity`.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById();
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag();
```

**EDIT**:- Question wasn't clear enough . What OP want to achieve can be simply done with `startActivityForResult();`. Please see [How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change to order inside [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()). Move `super.onBackPressed();` at the end of function. Check below:

Current is:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    FragmentProfile fragment = new FragmentProfile();
    fragment.refreshFragment();
}
```

Change to:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentProfile fragment = new FragmentProfile();
    fragment.refreshFragment();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Also make below changes to `refreshFragment()` method. Get the `Fragment` you want to refresh by `TAG`.

```
public void refreshFragment(){
    Fragment fragment = null;
    fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Fragment_TAG_You_want_to_refresh");
    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.detach(fragment).attach(fragment).commit();
}
```

Check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Adding) for how to add unique tag to a fragment.

Comment: not working, the error message show the FragmentTransaction is null. why?

Comment: @WanJern please check my updated answer for `refreshFragment()` method.

Comment: I assume you didn't read the question? the error is that the fragment manager is null, which is obvious given that the fragment it's being called from is a new Fragment, not yet attached.

Comment: I fail to see how that changes anything. You are not even using this `frg` Fragment you declared

Comment: I get this red error. Cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager()'

Comment: can't you see that the problem is in those 2 lines: `FragmentProfile fragment = new FragmentProfile();
    fragment.refreshFragment();` ?

Comment: @njzk2 I don't find any problem here `FragmentProfile fragment = new FragmentProfile(); fragment.refreshFragment();` He is just calling `refreshFragment()` from **his** `FragmentProfile` using object of `FragmentProfile`.

Comment: how do you expect to access a fragment manager from a fragment that was just created and has not been attached yet?

Comment: @Lester did you check my updated answer? Let me know if it is working or not. If not what error you are getting?

Comment: @Lester can you please make sure that you have imported `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` & `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;`